# Build fail when trying to use ObjectiveC code in Swift

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to use one of my Objective-C class from another target, in my Swift class inside extension target.
I created the `<Project-Name>-Bridging-Header.h` and included that objective-c file, but the build is not compiling  because of build error in `"Cryptor.h"` and `<CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>`. I believe this has to do something with CommonCrypto framework.
This is how my Bridging-Header.h looks:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
#import <Security/Security.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
```

I guess this is due to **Common Crypto** library. Has anybody encountered the same issue and solved it?

**EDIT**:
Specifically, i am getting build error - "Missing @end" in **CommonDigest.h** and because CommonDigest.h is not getting build hence the error in Cryptor.h.

Comment: What is this nebulous  "Build Error" of which you speak?

Comment: I have updated the question with an edit

Comment: I believe you're running into some of the "fun sides" of Objective-C++. Sometimes all it could mean is you forgot a method between @ implementation and @ end. Sometimes it means that for some reason the compiler is complaining that you have C++ code in an Objective-C context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will fix your problem, but the bridge-header is sometimes a bit buggy. At least it was the case for me.

Try to edit your header and import your files like that:

```
#import "FacebookSDK.h"
#import "GooglePlus.h"
#import "Security.h"
#import "CommonCrypto.h"
#import "CommonDigest.h"
```

I have removed the UIKit-header, because you don't really need it, because swift has it's own UIKit.